# NLog File target and keepFileOpen flag

Tags: c#, nlog

A FileTarget object in NLog has a property (bool) called "keepFileOpen".
By default this property is set to false, meaning that each log event will open the file, write in the file and close the file.

The hit in performance is huge, so I specified "keepFileOpen" to true, instead of false, meaning that the file will be opened only once.

Does anybody has an idea (or just know) why this property is by default set to "false", incuring a HUGE performance hit on logging ?

Is there any scenarios where setting this property to true can cause issues (which would therefore make sense to default it to "false").

Thanks !

**EDIT**

Performance measurements for basic layout, writing 100K events to the logger :

- keepFileOpen = false (default) : ~ 101 sec
- keepFileOpen = true : ~ 1 sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to send them an email and ask them about it. I cannot figure out any reason why this option is false by default.

Answer (score 10):

I would say that closing the file is the expected behaviour. If you will try to access the file from another process or delete it in file system while the NLog-process is alive it would lead to those annoying system-errors saying that some process holds the file etc.

If the time of opening a file is too long for you, try using the AsyncWrapper and you'll get a fire-and-forget-behavior.

Therefore I think that the default value is ok.

Answer (score 0):

The default value 'false' make no sense. The expected behavior is fast and reasonable.

And keepFileOpen should never hold the file, because there is a `FileStream` flag called `FileShare.ReadWrite`.